# Hibernate, save the datas from a Map

Tags: java, hibernate

i want to save the datas on hibernate dynamically from a Map(like HashMap).

```
String entityname = "table1";
Map<String,Object> myMap;

session.save(entityname, myMap);
```

My HashMap has informations like : 
{videoResolution=921600}

but i get following error :

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: table1
```

My Hibernate configuration file configured default-entity-mode :

```
    <property name="default_entity_mode">dynamic-map</property>
```

May you help me?

i've founded :

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession(); 
Session ds = session.getSession(EntityMode.MAP);
```

to save a map to the db vai Hibernate but i get always same error...

Thanks :)

Comment: This does not make much sense I'm afraid. I think you really need to go to the hibernate website and read a few tutorials before proceeding

Comment: This is qualifying for DailyWTF. No offence intended.

Answer (score 2):

Erm, Hibernate is an Object-Relational Mapping framework.  Consequently, you need both an Object (containing the data to be persisted) and a Mapping (to describe how the object's attributes should be put into certain database tables to use it).

There's no way to avoid this fundamental requirement, just like you can't run a Java application without a Main class no matter how much you might want to.

The [Hibernate documentation](http://www.hibernate.org/docs.html) is very comprehensive, so I recommend looking at [Getting Started](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/) guide and following it through.  You'll notice as well from the API that [session.save](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#save) requires a **persistent** class for an argument (i.e. one with a known mapping), which is unlikely to be the case for `java.util.Map`.

Comment: with this code, i could the persist data since now, but now i get this error :)

Comment: Your code still wouldn't compile.  And something tells me you haven't read the Hibernate documentation yet...

Comment: Isn't it theoretically possible to create a native sql query which can perform save or update?

Comment: [Yes](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#querysql-cud), but you still need a mapping through which to specify the query, and of course you still need the object to provide the bind variables.  And if this is *all* you're doing with Hibernate, you should just use JDBC directly.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate without objects or mapping?  I'd say you don't want Hibernate - try iBatis or straight JDBC instead.  What's Hibernate buying you here?  *Nothing*.

If you have a Map of (key, value) pairs that you want to store in a table, do it like this:

```
public interface TableMapper<K extends Serializable, V>
{
   Map<K, V> find();
   V find(K key);
   void save(Map<K, V> m);
   void update(Map<K, V> m);
   void delete(K key);
}
```

Implement this interface in Hibernate or iBatis or JDBC or JDO or JPA.  It'll let you do CRUD operations using a Java Map with a backing data store.

Comment: i've founded :

 Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
 Session ds = session.getSession(EntityMode.MAP);

to save a map to the db vai Hibernate but i get always same error...